# How to communicate with SWF objects?

Tags: html, flash, swfobject

I have some flash games (.swf files) embedded in my website.
I'm wondering if I could get data (like the final game score) from them, to create a "top players" database?

Is there any way to get this data from the swf object without recompiling the file?

Comment: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html

Answer (score 1):

You could send the data ( the score, for example ) to a php file ( or maybe asp ) and store it in a database.
example:

```
function SendRequest(dataToBeStoredInDB:URLVariables, callback:Function):void 
{
var urlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest("/path/to/phpfile/on/server.php");
urlReq.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

urlReq.data = dataToBeStoredInDB;

var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(urlReq);
loader.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, callback_function );
loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
loader.load(urlReq);
}
```

Comment: Is this a JavaScript? Where should I put this? And how does it know which .swf I'm trying to access?

Comment: no, this is as3 code. I don't know if I've got you right, but suppose that after a user has played the game, and his score is shown, this function sends the data(the score) to the specified php or asp file, and there, the data will be written to a database.

Comment: If I've understood you're question correctly, then you wouldn't need JS at all.